# Ember 0.9.6 performances update - Significant?

Tags: performance, binding, ember.js

I was naturally drawn to Ember's nice API/design/syntax compared to the competitors but was very saddened to see the performance was significantly worse. (For example, see the now well known http://jsfiddle.net/samdelagarza/ntMdB/167/ .) My eyes tell me at least 4 times slower than Backbone in Chrome.

The version 0.9.6 of EmberJS apparently has many performance fixes, in particular around bindings and rendering. However the above benchmark still performs poorly when using this version of Ember.

I see the above benchmark as demonstrative of one framework's binding cost. I come from Flex where bindings perform well enough that you don't have to constantly think whether these 5 bindings per renderer (multiplied by maybe 20 renderers) you want to use aren't going to be too much of an overhead. Ease of use is nice, but only if good enough performance is maintained. (Even more so since HTML5 also often targets mobiles).

As it stands, I tend to think the beauty of Ember is not worth the performance hit compared to some of its competitors, as we're talking about big apps with many bindings here, else you wouldn't need such framework in the first place. I could live with Ember performing slightly less well; after all it brings more to the table.

So my questions are fairly general and open:

- Is the Ember part of the benchmark written well enough that it shows
  a genuine issue?
- Are the 0.9.6 performance updates maybe very low
  key?
- Are the areas of bad performances identified by the main
  contributors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't really an issue of bindings being slow, but doing more DOM updates than necessary. We have been doing some investigation into this particular issue and we have some ideas for how to coalesce these multiple operations into one, so I do expect this to improve in the future.

That said, I can't see that this is a realistic benchmark. I would never recommend doing heavy animation in Ember (or with Backbone, for that matter). In standard app development, you shouldn't ever have to update that many different views simultaneous with that frequency.

If you can point out slow areas in a normal app we would be very happy to investigate. Performance is of great concern to us, and if things are truly slow during normal operation, we would consider that a bug. But, like I said, performant binding driven animations is not one of our goals, nor do I know of anyone for whom it is. Ember generally plays well with other libraries so it should be possible to plug in an animation library to do the animations outside of Ember.

Comment: Fair enough! I'm only evaluating the various frameworks at the moment so I'm afraid I don't know how Ember would perform in a big, "normal" application. But in particular, I was thinking it may struggle a bit with ticking prices/visual indicators in a grid or two, from seeing the above benchmark.

Comment: For what it's worth, Square is using Ember in combination with D3 for their new payment analytics page. You can read a bit about it here: http://corner.squareup.com/2012/04/building-analytics.html

Comment: Agreed with the fiddle as an inappropriate benchmark for most use cases. However, if you did need to do that kind of animation in Ember, you would want to craft your code to minimize DOM updates. Kris Selden forked the jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/krisselden/uz6Lt/

Comment: Here is the corresponding HN discussion: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3616820

Comment: I believe the performance hit is less of the "bindings inner workings", but rather the side-effect of the larger DOM (with all the extra, `<script>` tags that bindings inject as placeholders). This is based on the fact that you can get similar performance as KO by simply using the word 'unbound' in the template tag: `{{ model.content }}`. This breaks the comparison of apples to apples, but notice that we still have other bindings in place with the `{{ bindAttr ... }}` tags which doesn't use <script> tags and doesn't seem to affect the performance nearly as much as the straight bind tags do.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mkoistinen/ntMdB/216/.  Here I've changed all the templates to use <input> rather than a <div> for each box.  This allows Ember to avoid the heavy injection of <script type="text/x-placeholder"> tags and use much lighter weight bindAttr tags to set the value of the input, which is very similar to the way that KO and Backbone do things anyway.  The result is a noticeable performance improvement in performance from Ember. Still not as fast as the others, but only marginally slower now compared to Backbone.  KO is still the clear winner though in terms of speed.

Comment: Update the fiddle again to use setProperties() rather than a number of set()s (just like Backbone is doing) and I think that Ember is marginally faster now vs. Backbone.

http://jsfiddle.net/mkoistinen/ntMdB/217/